# Ignore everything in a folder except a few specific files and folders?

Tags: svn, svnignore

I know how to ignore everything in a folder by going into the folders properties and using:

```
svn:ignore *
```

However what if you wanted to do that but just wanted to version a few files and or folders? Can you just click on them and `Add` them or will the ignore override this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct you can just `svn add file` them and then the files won't be ignored.